# Laravel: inject view in another view through Controller static function

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, laravel-blade

I'm looking for inject into a blade view, another blade view called from Controller like this:

**VIEW-1:**

```
@inject('myController', 'App\Http\Controllers\MyController')
........
<div>
{{ $myController::getHi()}}
</div>
.......
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public static function getHi() {
    return view('users/hi-user');
}
```

**HI-USER VIEW:**

```
<p>Hi, <strong>how</strong> are you?</p>
```

But, it shows on VIEW-1 `<p>Hi, <strong>how</strong> are you?</p>` (not formated HTML) instead

> Hi, **how** are you?

How can I resolve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{!! $myController::getHi() !!}` instead of `{{ $myController::getHi() }}`.

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's  htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>   `Hello, {!! $name !!}.`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade